AWS Cloudformation: Export a variable exported in a codebuild action within a Codepipeline?
I have a cloudformation yaml which contains a codepipeline resource, which has a build action which exports a environment varaible. I can pass / reference that variable within later pipeline actions by assigning a namespace and referening it such as, for example:
"ImageTag": "#{PackageNamespace.IMAGE_TAG}"

How can then I export this at the stack level (i.e. in the stack outputs section, how can a point to the aforementioned variable?
I've tried like this:
  Outputs:
      ImageTag:
        Value: !Sub "#{PackageNamespace.IMAGE_TAG}"
        Export:
          Name: !Sub "${AWS::StackName}-ImageTag"

but that doesn't work

If the variable is being created inside a build action, CloudFormation doesn't have a way to know what it is. Once the build is running, CloudFormation is no longer involved. The value would need to be available to CloudFormation during the stack operation.
